# is it possible to get information about my google profile programmatically for the default domain?

Tags: api

looking at this:

code.google.com/apis/apps/profiles/developers_guide_protocol.html

it seems that the oauth protected resource is per domain and on behalf of administrators:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/example.com/full/liz

1. is it possible to access user's feeds programmatically for the google.com domain ?
2. if so, what is the domain for the default public google domain (not my own example.com domain. doesn't seem to be google.com neither default) ?

eg

www.google.com/profiles/100193566679817641096

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is no. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/profiles/developers_guide_protocol.html) states:

> Note: This API is only available to Google Apps Premier, Education,
>   and Partner Edition domains, and cannot be used for accessing or
>   editing Google Apps Standard Edition or Gmail profiles.

However, you may be able to retrieve some of the same info using the Google Portable Contacts API: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/poco/1.0/developers_guide.html#RetrievingUserContact